# How to do parellel bootstrap on different machine using chef?

Tags: automation, chef-infra, bootstrapping

Suppose I have written five different recipes and I have five different target nodes.

How can I fire a bootstrap command that will address all 5 nodes at ones and it will execute the specified recipes(one for one) in parallel on each target node.

Comment: Could u plz elaborate?

Comment: Checkout spiceweasel and the emerging chef-metal projects

Comment: Chef-metal is the best way we have found to batch converge machines.  It runs good with chef-zero and Chef Enterprise.  If you would like help I can send you some examples of getting it to work nice.  Right now we are orchestrating about 30-50 servers at a time with one command.

Answer (score 0):

There is way to bootstrap multiple cookbooks on multiple machines at a time using spiceweasel . In this first install the spiceweasel package on the node . U need to create a yaml file and load ur data in the file .. like node  ip , cookbook name .

go through this link , it will give you an idea

https://github.com/mattray/spiceweasel#cookbooks