# Bootstrap on multiple nodes at a time through a single command

Tags: knife, chef-infra

Can i bootstrap a cookbook on multiple nodes at a time through a single bootstrap command . I mean the following way

```
knife bootstrap IP1 IP2 -x user1 -x user2 -P pwd1 -P pwd2 -r recipe[cookbook]
```

Is this possible or any other alternative method is available ..?
Let me know if i am wrong .

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263739/how-to-do-parellel-bootstrap-on-different-machine-using-chef

Answer (score 0):

Not through knife bootstrap itself - you can see from the [command documentation](http://docs.getchef.com/knife_bootstrap.html) that it only accepts one IP or hostname as an argument. To get the behavior you described you could write a simple wrapper script that would take in multiple IPs and run each bootstrap command in a separate thread or process.